# Inner product in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ involving exponential term

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be an open bounded domain. Let $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ and consider
$$g(u):= e^{\alpha u^2}-1,$$
with $\alpha>0$.
As an exercise, it is left to evaluate
$$(g(su), u)\quad u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$$
where $(\cdot, \cdot)$ denotes the inner product in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ and $s\ge 0$.

This is my solution: Since $(u, v)=\int_{\Omega} \nabla u\cdot\nabla v dx$ for any $u, v\in H^1_0(\Omega)$, it is
$$(g(su), u)=\int_{\Omega}\nabla (e^{\alpha s^2 u^2}-1)\cdot \nabla u dx =\int_{\Omega}2\alpha s^2 u e^{\alpha s^2 u^2} \nabla u\cdot\nabla u dx =2\alpha s^2 \int_{\Omega}u e^{\alpha s^2 u^2} |\nabla u|^2 dx.$$

Could someone please tell me if it is true?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: looks right to me

Comment: Could you explain what is $H_0^1(\Omega)$ ?